# Mapping a type to a function of that type in c++

Tags: c++, function, class, unordered-map

Let's suppose I have a character that can have 1 out of 3 states at a time(crouching, jumping and walking). For each of the 3 states I have a function of type void() that does whatever they are assigned to. I also have an enum that stores the different states and a number for each state.

```
class Player {
private:
   enum State {
       crouching = 0,
       walking= 1,
       jumping = 2
   } state;
}
```

I also have an unordered map that is used to link the different states to their funtions.

```
class Player {
private:
   std::unordered_map<int, void(Player::*)()> stateToFunc;

   void playerJump(){ /* code here */ };
   void playerCrouch(){ /* code here */ };
   void playerWalk(){ /* code here */ };

   Player() {
        // other stuff
        stateToFunc[0] = playerCrouch;
        stateToFunc[1] = playerWalk;
        stateToFunc[2] = playerJump;
}
```

I made it so everytime I press a certain key, the state variable will update.
My goal is so on each update I will call only the function `stateToFunc[state]` instead of checking manually with a switch statement.
It gives me the following error:

```
 Error  C3867   'Player::gActivated': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

If I use `stateToFunc[0] = & playerCrouch;`, it gives me other errors. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: If those are actually member functions (hard to tell since you didn't include a proper [mre]) then you get a pointer to it via `&Player::playerJump`

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: In `std::unordered_map<int, void(Player::*)()> stateToFunc;` it looks like the `int` should be `State`. When you play mix-n-match with `int`s and `enum`s you're just asking for bugs to creep in. If you use the correct types, the compiler can trap most of the screw ups before you find you've wasted an afternoon debugging something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what the compiler tells you - use the `&` operator to get a pointer to a member method. You will also have to specify the class the methods belong to, eg:

```
class Player {
private:
   std::unordered_map<State, void(Player::*)()> stateToFunc;

   void playerJump(){ /* code here */ };
   void playerCrouch(){ /* code here */ };
   void playerWalk(){ /* code here */ };

   Player() {
        // other stuff
        stateToFunc[crouching] = &Player::playerCrouch;
        stateToFunc[walking] = &Player::playerWalk;
        stateToFunc[jumping] = &Player::playerJump;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, to actually call the methods, you can use the `->*` operator, like this:

```
void Player::doSomething()
{
    ...
    (this->*stateToFunc[state])();
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::function` instead, with either `std::bind()` or lambdas, eg:

```
class Player {
private:
   std::unordered_map<State, std::function<void()>> stateToFunc;

   void playerJump(){ /* code here */ };
   void playerCrouch(){ /* code here */ };
   void playerWalk(){ /* code here */ };

   Player() {
        // other stuff

        stateToFunc[crouching] = std::bind(&Player::playerCrouch, this);
        stateToFunc[walking] = std::bind(&Player::playerWalk, this);
        stateToFunc[jumping] = std::bind(&Player::playerJump, this);
        // or:
        stateToFunc[crouching] = [this](){ playerCrouch(); };
        stateToFunc[walking] = [this](){ playerWalk(); };
        stateToFunc[jumping] = [this](){ playerJump(); }
    }

    ...
}
```

```
void Player::doSomething()
{
    ...
    stateToFunc[state]();
    ...
}
```